# Definition list disc not showing up

Tags: html, css

CSS:

```
.about dt { 
list-style-type:none;
font-weight:bold;

}
.about dd { 
list-style-type: disc;
list-style-position: outside;
margin-left: 0px;
padding-left: 30px;
}
```

And the html

```
<dl class="about">
    <dt>Current topics and titles </dt>
    <dd>Fulfilling community residents&rsquo; appetite for information about 
    popular cultural and social trends and their desires for satisfying 
    recreational experiences</dd>
...
```

I want a disc before the DD, but it's not showing up in Chrome or IE. Any ideas what I've done wrong?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use the `:before` pseudo-element in CSS to insert the bullet character just before every `<dd>` or use a background-image on it with a bullet which would also make it cross-browser as :before isn't supported in all browsers.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the `list-style-type` is meant for, well, `ul/ol/li` (lists). and not definition tags.

You should rewrite your syntax to use a list, or perhaps add `&bull;`(•) infront of the definitions.

Comment: Right you are. Thanks! The only downside to adding the bull is I wouldn't be able to easily have it duplicate `list-style-position: outside;` ... Oh well, you can't have everything, where would you put it?

Comment: I would just put it as the first thing in the `<dt>` tag.  You might be able to write some javascript to go and add all the bullet points, but for the most part, if you want a CSS option, you have to use a list.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Stagas, use a background image on the `<dd>` of your def. list.  You don't want to add special characters to the mark-up itself...remember, keep content separate from presentation. Pseudo-elements aren't going to render in IE 7 and earlier.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a demo of stagas' approach:

http://jsfiddle.net/snifty/eLXyu/1/

```
.about dt:before {
  content: "\25CF";
  font-size:x-large;
  color:maroon;    
}

.about dt {
  font-weight:bold;
}
.about dd {
  margin-left: 0px;
  padding-left: 30px;
}
```

I used a particular Unicode character to emulate the disk. Pseudo-elements are [way fun](http://css-tricks.com/pseudo-element-roundup/).